# Как отключить Collecting Changes в TeamCity?

Tags: teamcity

TeamCity 9, git.

Есть билд конфигурация для деплоя, запускается вручную по тэгу - BuildAndDeploy.

Есть билд конфигурация для мержа, AutoBuildMerge, запускается автоматом по изменению в определенных ветках, при успешном билде создает тег (который используется в первом билде).

Проблема заключается в том, что шаг Collecting Changes на BuildAndDeploy может идти непредсказуемо долго. От 1 минуты до нескольких часов. Подозреваю, что это потому, BuildAndDeploy работает по тегам, которые могут принадлежать разным веткам, и сбор изменений между двумя тегами может достигать нескольких тысяч, в то время как в пределах одной ветки, еще и инкрементивно 1-2.

Собственно вопросы:

1) Я неправильно работаю с ТимСити, и если я хочу делать билды по тегам, нужно делать отдельную билд конфигурацию для каждой ветки? Или это не так работает?

2) Что-то не то с ТимСити? К сожалению, административного доступа нет, смотреть логи ТимСити и ставить плагины нет возможности, управляю только билд агентами.

3) Можно ли отключить вообще этот collecting changes для конкретной билд конфигурации (нам вполне достаточно видеть это в мерж билдах)

P.S. Поиск по гуглу конкретно мою проблему не решил совсем, парочку похожих ситуаций описаны несколько лет назад и связаны с CVS/SVN... но ничего не помогло.

Comment: 1 вопрос не очень понятен. можете перефразировать или объяснить?

Comment: приложите к вопросу весь билд лог от начала до запуска

Comment: а ты указываешь `Clean all files in the checkout directory before the build` перед запуском ?

Comment: clean all files не важен. Шаг collecting changes идет ДО checkout source, это фича самого ТимСити, чтобы показывать изменения между билдами в веб UI. До самого билдагента, где начинается билд, в это время еще дело не доходит.

Comment: Приложить весь лог нельзя, NDA, но в логе ничего полезного нет - там выполняется шаг Collecting Changes, он выполняется непосредственно на ТимСити сервере, а не на билд агенте. А внутренних логов ТимСити сервера, как и доступа к шелле где он запущен - нет.

Comment: в этом шаге отображается инфа о сканируемых репозиториев. может у тебя репо слишком большое? Default branch: что стоит ?попробуй только один бранч указать в vcs root

Comment: Я вообще не указываю там branch, default branch пустой, то есть по дефолту он считается master, в котором у нас вообще ничего не ведется.
На этом этапе в логе только две строчки
Collecting changes in 1 VCS root
   VCS Root details (его уникальное название)

Comment: пробуйте указать отдельно конкретный бранч. 
пробуйте скопировать репо полностью со всей историей, и попробовать уже с новой репозиторием

Comment: Как указать отдельный бранч, если я делаю билд на конкретный тэг?
Там или бранч или тэг.
Смысл копирования всего репо со всей историей? Репозиторий достаточно большой. И билды не всегда глючат. Давайте подождем человека, который может подсказать что именно происходит.

Comment: установите галочку "Use tags as branches:". теперь все тэги как бранчи. укажите конкретный бранч, то есть тэг

Comment: Без этой галочки вообще нельзя было бы собирать по тэгу.
Естественно она включена.

В общем проблема пока решилась почти сама собой, к сожалению нигде нет документации о том, как именно под капотом работает Collecting Changes, и что вызвало такие проблемы.